# Addressing part of a string via the array syntax in Python

Tags: python, string

Is it, in Python, possible to address a specific character in a string by the standard array syntax?

Example, PHP:

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo $foo[1]; // Output: a
```

It didn't work like in PHP so I wanted to know if it is possible using some other way?

Comment: where is your Python code that produces an error?

Comment: When you have a problem, it is good to show people the code that has the problem.  You get better answers that way and less irritated people looking at your questions and scratching their heads.

Comment: -1: No code to clarify the actual issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Adam pointed out, reading from a string array is possible in Python using the indexing syntax. What isn't possible though is writing to a string using this syntax:

```
>>> s = 'bar'
>>> s[2] = 'z'
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Maybe this was the problem you ran into?

Comment: +1 for an educated guess at what the problem might have been.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works. In fact, it works exactly like it does in PHP. The only difference is that variable names in Python are not preceeded by the `$` character.

```
foo = 'bar'
print foo[1] # Output: a
```

Is Python, strings are one of a number of sequence types. You can find all of the operations that you can perform on sequence types in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange).